# Can you reference an aggregate function on a temporary row in an insert statement within a stored procedure in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql-11

I am writing a postgres stored procedure that loops through the rows returned from a select statement. For each row it loops through, it inserts values from that select statement into a new table. One of the values I need to insert into the second table is the average of a column. However, when I call the stored procedure, I get an error that the temporary row has no attribute for the actual column that I am averaging. See stored procedure and error below.

Stored Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure sendToDataset(sentence int)
as $$
declare temprow peoplereviews%rowtype;
BEGIN

  FOR temprow IN
      select rulereviewid, avg(rulereview)
      from peoplereviews 
      where sentenceid = sentence
      group by rulereviewid
  loop
      insert into TrainingDataSet(sentenceId, sentence, ruleCorrectId, ruleCorrect, dateAdded)
          values(sentence, getSentenceFromID(sentence), tempRow.rulereviewid, tempRow.avg(rulereview), current_timestamp);
    END LOOP;

END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "rulereview" does not exist
LINE 2: ...omID(sentence), tempRow.rulereviewid, tempRow.avg(rulereview...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  insert into TrainingDataSet(sentenceId, sentence, ruleCorrectId, ruleCorrect, dateAdded)
          values(sentence, getSentenceFromID(sentence), tempRow.rulereviewid, tempRow.avg(rulereview), current_timestamp)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sendtodataset(integer) line 11 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42703
```

Basically, I am wondering if it's possible to use that aggregate function in the insert statement or not and if not, if there is another way around it.

Comment: Are you sure the values are listed in the right order? Given the names of the target columns, I'd assume it should be `values(getsentenceid(sentence), sentence, ...`

Comment: Yes, because sentence represents the sentenceID (postgres wouldn't let me use sentenceID as the parameter name because it said it was ambiguous) and getsentencefromID(sentence) gets the actual sentence given the sentenceID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use a slow and inefficient loop for this:

```
 insert into TrainingDataSet(sentenceId, sentence, ruleCorrectId, ruleCorrect, dateAdded)
 select getSentenceId(sentence), sentence, rulereviewid, avg(rulereview), current_timestamp
 from peoplereviews 
 where sentenceid = sentence
 group by rulereviewid
```

---

To answer the original question: you need to provide a proper alias for the aggregate:

```
  FOR temprow IN
      select rulereviewid, avg(rulereview) as avg_views
      from peoplereviews 
      where sentenceid = sentence
      group by rulereviewid
  loop
      insert into TrainingDataSet(sentenceId, sentence, ruleCorrectId, ruleCorrect, dateAdded)
      values(sentence, getSentenceFromID(sentence), tempRow.rulereviewid, 
             tempRow.avg_views, current_timestamp);
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked great! I had tried doing what you suggested in the second part of your answer, however when I tried using an alias, I would get an error saying that temprow had no attribute "rulereviewid" or any other attribute I tried to reference.